# Filter flash content from html

Tags: php, apache

I was wondering how I can filter flash content from a specific html file.

I know I can use regex and search for .swf or .flv files, but is there another way of getting flash movies from a html document?

I want to use PHP to get the links to the flash content in an html file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, you can regex'em: [Google: php regular expressions flash swf](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+regular+expressions+flash+swf)

Answer (score 1):

Use a DOM parser and look for object/embed elements that are hardcoded and parse to see if the src / data attribute values contain .swf with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but you could just look for the structure. For instance flash content is typically loaded in the  tag.  Once you have that you can parse through it grabbing the info you need by simply grabbing the content of the 'data' attribute in non-IE browsers, or in IE the

Using jQuery to grab those values for PHP to grab would make your life infinitely simpler as well.

Comment: Ok but the problem is that many times I can't find the URL of the video. For example, look at southparkstudios[dot]com and click on a movie. You can find the swf of the player, but no file the player plays....

Comment: @CyberK  the issue there is most likely due to 2 possible scenarios:


1) They hardcode the movie sources inside the compiled SWF file. In which case there is no way for PHP to grab that information.

2) The swf file contains a hardcoded reference to an XML file, webservice or database that contains the movie sources (paths). If an XML file is being used and you can find/access it, then you can easily parse that with PHP/JS/etc...  if they have gone the WS/DB route then much like scenario one you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');
foreach($html->find('object') as $element) {
//now you can access the <object> tags attributes like
echo $element->id;
//usually flash is embedded in an <object> tag, so you can just wipe the contents of it with
$element->innertext='';
}
```

Comment: Ok cool, but is there also a way for finding the swf sources? For instance, you have a player and I need the source of the file it plays. How can I get that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could use foreach($html->find('embed') as $element) and then $element->src would return the swf file.